# How many $7$-digit numbers are there with non-repeating digits?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, combinations

I have to find the amount of all $7$-digit numbers with non-repeating digits (every digit should be in the number only once). And also I have to find such a number with digits whose sum gives minimal possible number. I do not know how to approach that :/

Comment: Are zeros on the left allowed? (is $0000019$ a seven digits number?)

Comment: Waht have you tried?

Comment: It's a basic problem. It should be the first, second, or third example in *any* text book on cominatorics.  Hint:  How many choices do you have for the first digit.  Given that you have chosen the first digit, how many remaining choices do you have for the second and so on.

Comment: The sum being the smallest possible.  Well what can that sum be?  Can it be 63?  No, because $0+1 + 2+3 + 4+5+6 < 63$.  Can it be $32$.  No, because $0 + 1 + 2+3+4+5+6 < 32$ can it be $12$?  No, because $0 + 1 + 2+ 3+ 4 +5+6 > 12$.... Can it be.....

Answer (score 1):

Using the multiplication rule we get total number of 7 digit numbers as $9*9*8*7*6*5*4=544320$

The reasoning for this can be given as : For the first digit of the number we can select any of the nine of the nine digits from 1 to 9, for the second digit we can select any digit from 0 to 9 excluding the one which we have already placed in the first position . For the third place we have 8 options to choose from 0 to 9 excluding the digits we already placed on first and second positions. Hence the answer appears.

Also there will be $6*6*5*4*3*2*1=4320$ seven digit numbers having the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ giving minimum sum as 21. The reasoning is same as above.

Comment: If the OP couldn't figure this out on her/his own, I don't see that the OP will be able to reason why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Let us compute the number $a_n$ of $n$-different digits numbers which do *not* start with $0$. Clearly $a_n=0$ whenever $n>10$. Moreover
$$
a_n=9 \cdot (9 \cdot 8 \cdots (11-n))
$$
if $n=1,\ldots,10$ (the second product is $1$ if $n=1$). The reason is that you have $9$ possibilities for the first digit on the left: all except $0$. Then, you will have $9$ possibilities for the second digit (including $0$), $8$ possibilities for the third one, etc.

Hence your answer is
$$
a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_7.
$$